# Get all child elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium with Python is it possible to get all the children of a WebElement as a list?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it by `find_elements_by_css_selector("*")` or `find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")`.

However, this doesn't sound like a valid use case to find **all children** of an element. It is an expensive operation to get all direct/indirect children. Please further explain what you are trying to do. There should be a better way.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")

header = driver.find_element_by_id("header")

# start from your target element, here for example, "header"
all_children_by_css = header.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
all_children_by_xpath = header.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")

print 'len(all_children_by_css): ' + str(len(all_children_by_css))
print 'len(all_children_by_xpath): ' + str(len(all_children_by_xpath))
```

Comment: just figure out that the `.` before `//` is important,    if the dot is missing,  even if you are calling the method from an element,  it again search the whole HTML

Comment: Can we use this way to locate a specific child, or the next immediate child? or a whole path, starting from the parent?

Answer (score 94):

Yes, you can use `find_elements_by_` to retrieve children elements into a list.  See the python bindings here:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Example HTML:

```html
<ul class="bar">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

You can use the `find_elements_by_` like so:

```py
parentElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bar")
elementList = parentElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

If you want help with a specific case, you can edit your post with the HTML you're looking to get parent and children elements from.

Comment: * find_element_by_class_name

Answer (score 10):

In 2022, with `selenium==4.2.0`, @Richard's answer will need to be rewritten as:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

parentElement = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"bar")
elementList = parentElement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"li")
```

Comment: This wont work!

Answer (score 7):

Another variation of `find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")` is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_attribute` and `BeautifulSoup`

```
html_str = el.get_attribute('innerHTML')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use

```
all_children_by_css = header.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
```

You now need to use

```
all_children_by_css = header.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*")
```