# How to iterate a unordered list in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html-lists

I would like to iterate through the below elements in Python using Selenium webdriver.

```
<ul class="skills-section">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Ear Surgery">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Healthcare">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Hospitals">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Surgery">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Medical Education">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Pediatrics">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Treatment">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Public Health">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Patient Safety">
  <li class="endorse-item has-endorsements " data-endorsed-item-name="Emergency Medicine">
</ul>
```

What I tried?

```
skillsSection = a.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'skills-section')]")
skillsList = skillsSection.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for skill in skillsList:
    print skill.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,endorse-item-name')]/a").text
```

But the problem is, it is always printing the first element value. The element is not incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is find the tag `'ul'` with `class='skills-section'` and then iterate over the children.

```
skillsSection = a.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'skills-section')]")
for child in skillsSection.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*"):
    ...
```

See this answer too for more details: [Selenium Python get all children elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/selenium-python-get-all-children-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar issue recently where I could only print the first item in a list.  I discovered a solution that requires multiple lines, and avoids using xpaths.  For your code, you may want to replace:

```
print skill.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'endorse-item-name')]/a").text
```

with something like:

```
a1 = skill.find_element_by_class_name('endorse-item-name')
a2 = a1.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
print a2.text
```

Not as elegant as one line with xpath, but it (should) work.