# How to get first layer sub elements only in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get a list of only the first layer child elements in selenium python?

I want something similar to what is described here: [Selenium Python get all children elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/selenium-python-get-all-children-elements)

However, I only want the first layer sub elements. I have attached a picture to explain.

[sub list problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXNGH.png)

if I do as is described in the other entry I get all sub and sub sub....... elements. I just want the first layer like the 4 div elements shown in the image not the 8 sub sub elements.

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath("/*")`

Comment: I don't know how  find_element_by_xpath works with empty xpath string but that i've written:`/*` - slash means root, and asterisk means any element on that level.

Comment: Where are you code attempts? From your labeled screenshot, you don't want the first layer... you want the second layer. alecxe's answer shows you how to do that. You should probably spend some time reading up on CSS selectors and/or XPaths. This is a pretty basic question.

Answer (score 8):

**Updated as of version 4.8.3**

It's:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./*")
```

When you put `".//*"`, it gets all possible children in the tree, but with one slash `"./*"` only gets the children of the next level.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to specify a *direct parent-child relationship* which can be done in XPath via a single `/` and in CSS selectors via `>`:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//section[@id = 'irq']/div/div[@eid]")
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("section#irq > div > div[eid]")
```

Please recheck the `irq` and `eid` if I got them right from the screenshot (it is a bit blurry).

Comment: So all direct children in CSS for an element you already have in the code would be to query `>*` as css selector on that element?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like what you are looking for:

```python
>>> elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="first"]/div')
>>> [i.get_attribute('id') for i in elements]
['second-1', 'second-2', 'second-3']
```

**Sample html:**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="first">
      <div id="second-1"></div>
      <div id="second-2">
        <div id="third-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="second-3"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```