# How to get FIRST level children via Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I have seen quite a few replies but for some reason NONE of them work and they always return all the children not just FIRST level

Here is one such answer: [How to get first layer sub elements only in python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131039/how-to-get-first-layer-sub-elements-only-in-python-selenium/57315415#57315415)

They all suggest a CSS selector as in using nth-child(##)

Here is my data:

```
<**table**>
    <**tbody**>
        <**tr**>   // I want to only get this
            <**td**>td 1</td>
            <**tr**><td>Nested 1</td></**tr**>  // don't want this tr
            <**td**>td 2<**/td**>
            <**tr**><**/tr**>  // don't want this
            <**/tr**>
            <**tr**>   // I want to only get this
                <**td**>td 3<**/td**>
                <**tr**><**/tr**>  // don't want this
                <td>td 4</td>
                <tr></tr>  // don't want this
            </tr>
    <**/tbody**>
<**/table**>
```

Comment: it is important to format your code properly so others can understand

Comment: For better help, create and post a valid minimal reproducible example if at all possible.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Moshe This is like help to help yourself. The HTML provided by you is not valid one and hence not able to provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to put an `id` field on each element, so that such problems become trivial. If you can, do that, so that your selector is just `#my-id`.

However, barring that you have to do some kind of awkward selector. nth-child would work as long as you are certain that the element you want is fixed. In this case `table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)`

Barring that, you're out of luck in your exact case.