# Selecting required radio button with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, radio-button

I want to select one random radio button from each container/question  [link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeWJKoj2LG14pgNOaQOTBnDeXH6NNw8c90Q5mfcFeNNr75HMg/viewform?usp=sf_link)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
import Resources
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= Resources.driverChrome)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(Resources.linkTest)

time.sleep(3)
try:
    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
    if email.is_displayed() & email.is_enabled():
        email.send_keys(Resources.emailTest)
except:
    print("Email box was not found")

containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class ='freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer']")
sNoBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='text' ] ")

for sNOBox in sNoBoxes:
    sNOBox.send_keys(Resources.sNo)


time.sleep(2)
radios = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio exportOuterCircle']")
for radio in radios:
     radio.click()
```

i know this code is going through all the buttons so it ends up selecting the last one but i am not getting any way by which i can make the selections random.
I tried using random.choices to take out random buttons and then iterate through it to click a random button but its not working

```
ranBtns = random.choices(radios, k = 10)
for btn in ranBtns:
    btn.click
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are looping through each and every radio button and selecting them. So, naturally only the last radio button of each question is being selected. What you need to do is loop through each question and then randomly select a radio button by locating the element inside the parent element.

[Check this for information regarding getting all child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/get-all-child-elements)

I hope this will work out:

```
containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class ='freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer']")
for container in containers:
    radioOptions = container.find_elments_by_xpath("//div[@class='freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionRadioChoice freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionRadioOptionContainer']")
    if len(li) != 0:
        randIdx = numpy.random.randint(3)
        radioOptions[randIdx].click()
```

Please note that when you locate the container element may not always contain radio buttons so you need to check with the if condition.

Comment: Thanks for trying but i already tried both the approaches u mentioned , its still now working   [my code](https://github.com/sanjay-lakshmanan/test/commit/f89ef2daa54a87d3e933b16b9709d047e9b4f6c0)

Comment: You mentioned that you want to randomly select one radio button. However, in your code, you just try and loop through all the radio buttons, click the first element in the list and break the loop. So I am guessing the script will always select the first element. In my answer I have tried to select a random radio button by using random functionality of numpy. Have you tried that?

Comment: Did it work? Could you please update if it did or what how did you accomplish your task?

Comment: Ya it kind of worked but not exactly. Even though  i tried to select one option in ever compartment as you mentioned and selected a random option , it was taking the list of entire option in the page, i tried with almost every tag that enclosed the option but got the same result. So i took the list of all the radio buttons and selected few in random. Obviously few answers were unmarked but the work was done.  Still i will be happy if you are able to figure out a way to select 1 option from every compartment