# Python selenium - get text and href

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have multiple `divs` looking like this :

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">Text1</div>
        <div class="class4">
            <a href="https://somelink"><h2>Text2</h2></a>
            <p class="class5">Text3 <span class="class6"> Text4 </span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For each `div` I can get Text1, Text2, Text3, and Text4:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']/*")
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
    print('------------------------------------------')
```

But how do I additionaly get value of `href`?

I would like to have : https://somelink, Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']/*") # this will recognize "class2" 
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
    link = e.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").get_attribute("href") # Finds the "a" tag inside the class2. A "." at the beginning because we are finding element within elements. "//a" because "class2" is nested. 
    print('------------------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 1):

why not do this?

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']/*")
res = []
for e in elements:
    res.append(e.text)
    href = e.get_attribute('href')
    if href is not None:
        res.insert(0, href)
print(", ".join(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer here: [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862426/python-selenium-get-href-value/54862902)

Basically, it will look like

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.class4 > a').get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: But if I use css selector I will not be able to get href together with Text fields. As I said, there are multiple divs with class4 so using your solution I would get a list of hrefs and second list of text fields.

Comment: True. Sorry, I thought your primary issue was how to get href attribute, not all the attributes at once. In that case, I would first get all the parent elements (class2, for example), and then for each such element I'd queried separately all text blocks as you did already, and separately queried a link from corresponding href attribute. An example of how to query elements inside other elements is available there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/get-all-child-elements