# retrieving chrome driver element data from returned form

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a simple scraper with selenium to retrieve zip code for a given address, city, ST from this USPS tool: https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress

Here is my code which is working on most steps but I am struggling to get the data I need to retrieve at the very end (the zip code):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# step 1: set path to chromedriver downloaded from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
PATH = "chromedriver" # modify to location on your system of above downloaded driver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress")

# step 2: specify the address to search for 
street_address = "530 WILLIAM PENN PL"
city = "PITTSBURGH"
state = "PA"

# step 3: fill out the form with specified data in step 2
input_address = driver.find_element_by_id('tAddress')
input_city = driver.find_element_by_id('tCity')
drpState = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('tState'));

input_address.send_keys(street_address)
time.sleep(1)
input_city.send_keys(city)
time.sleep(1)
drpState.select_by_value(state)

# step 4: select "Find button" on USPS page to advance
button_find = driver.find_element_by_id('zip-by-address')
button_find.click()
time.sleep(2)

# step 5: retrieve zip code (the problem)
zipcode= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zipByAddressDiv"]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/p[3]/strong')

attrs=[]
for attr in zipcode.get_property('attributes'):
    attrs.append([attr['name'], attr['value']])
print(attrs)
```

As you can see in below screenshot, at the very end I specify an XPATH which I obtained by inspecting the zip code. I then try to list the attributes of the zipcode WebDriver object but it comes out empty, there is no error just nothing returns in the attributes of the object.

Would appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: you get `<string>` and it doesn't have any attributes. If page would be `<string name="..." value="...">` then you would get some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you try to use `get_attributes`.

To get some attributes this page would need `<strong name="..." value="...">` but it has only `<strong>`

If you want tag name then use `zipcode.tag_name`
and if you want text `15219-1820` inside `<strong> </strong>` then use `zipcode.text`

```
zipcode = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zipByAddressDiv"]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/p[3]/strong')

print(zipcode.tag_name)
print(zipcode.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly, I just needed the syntax for selecting that specific element and the attribute (tag_name) to pull it which I had not encountered while searching. Thank you again.

Comment: In Python command `print( dir(zipcode) )` can give names of all properties and functions in this object/class (as list of strings so you can use for-loop or `"\n".join()` to format it, or filter). You can also use `help(zipcode)` to see more information

Answer (score 0):

(Referencing off the image)
You could instead get the element `zipcode-by-address` and get it's child classes and find the **`strong`**

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
... # navigation stuff here.
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("zipcode-by-address")
all_children_by_xpath = header.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*") # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/get-all-child-elements
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I'm not sure I fully understand your codeblock or the answers on the question you referenced about getting all child elements. What would be my target element (the analog to the header element in that example)? Is that my zipcode WebDriver object? Doesn't seem so because then why are you specifying xpath again with find_elements_by_xpath on that same object?